# transforming timeslots using Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this data, with timeslots, I am trying to convert them to 15 minutes intervals for the same day.

(elixir 1.10.4,
erlang 23.1.4)

```
[
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[13:30:00],
    till: ~T[14:15:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[15:30:00],
    till: ~T[16:30:00],
  },
]
```

I am trying to convert it to this

```
[
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[13:30:00],
    till: ~T[13:45:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[13:45:00],
    till: ~T[14:00:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[14:00:00],
    till: ~T[14:15:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[15:30:00],
    till: ~T[15:45:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[15:45:00],
    till: ~T[16:00:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[16:00:00],
    till: ~T[16:15:00],
  },
  %{
    day: "fri",
    since: ~T[16:15:00],
    till: ~T[16:30:00],
  }
]
```

any help would be wonderful, I am unaware of how to handle indexes within an enum, So I can attach since and till with a map. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no overlapping input, we can use an infinite stream from `since` adding by `15` minutes until we hit `till`.

```elixir
input = [
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[13:30:00], till: ~T[14:15:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[15:30:00], till: ~T[16:30:00]}
]

Enum.flat_map(input, fn 
  %{day: day, since: since, till: till} ->
    since
    |> Stream.iterate(& &1 |> Time.add(15 * 60) |> Time.truncate(:second))
    |> Stream.chunk_every(2, 1)
    |> Stream.map(fn [s, t] -> %{day: day, since: s, till: t} end)
    |> Enum.reduce_while([], fn %{till: t} = e, acc ->
         if(Time.compare(t, till) != :gt,
           do: {:cont, [e|acc]},
           else: {:halt, acc})
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse()
end)
```

Comment: Hello, I was doing some testing when the pair is like this `%{day: "fri", since: ~T[00:00:00], till: ~T[23:45:00]}`  the reduce never comes back.

Comment: Yes when the since and till are like this, it just kept running in reduce_while.

Answer (score 0):

For each element of input we must split this item to list of 15 minute chunks and accumulate them:

```elixir
defmodule SomeModule do
  @spec split(binary(), Time.t(), Time.t(), list()) :: list()
  def split(day, t1, t2, acc) do
    cond do
      t2 <= t1 -> acc
      true ->
        t = Time.add(t1, 15 * 60) |> Time.truncate(:second)
        cond do
          t < t2 -> split(day, t, t2, acc ++ [%{day: day, since: t1, till: t}])
          true -> split(day, t2, t2, acc ++ [%{day: day, since: t1, till: t2}])
        end
    end
  end

  @spec convert(list()) :: list()
  def convert(l) do
    Enum.reduce(l, [], fn x, acc ->
      acc ++ split(x.day, x.since, x.till, [])
    end)
  end
end
```

If

```elixir
l = [%{day: "fri",since: ~T[13:30:00],till: ~T[14:15:00]},%{day: "fri",since: ~T[15:30:00],till: ~T[16:30:00]}]
```

Then we can get the result by:

```elixir
SomeModule.convert l
```

The output will be:

```elixir
[
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[13:30:00], till: ~T[13:45:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[13:45:00], till: ~T[14:00:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[14:00:00], till: ~T[14:15:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[15:30:00], till: ~T[15:45:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[15:45:00], till: ~T[16:00:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[16:00:00], till: ~T[16:15:00]},
  %{day: "fri", since: ~T[16:15:00], till: ~T[16:30:00]}
]
```